# how can i make the drop down menu title look more unique

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

May I know how can I make a gap between the drop down title? I tried adding `border:1px solid black;` but it's ugly. I wish to make it like `home | about | portfolio | blog | contact` instead of `home about portfolio blog contact`.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color:#2A0851;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(white, grey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;  
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a typo `-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;` plus in my chrome the button blinks invisible for 0.1 seconds when i hover it.

Comment: Thank for the correction @freestock.tk ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this below css where you can add border-left to main `<li>` and border-bottom to its child's check below updated css it may help you.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color:#2A0851;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(white, grey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;  
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
div>ul>li{
  border-left : 1px solid grey;
  }

div>ul>li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

div ul li ul li{
  border-bottom : 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use white bottom border and `-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;` as rightly suggested in comments by  freestock.tk

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color:#2A0851;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(white, grey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;  
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.bottom-separator{
  border-bottom:solid 1px white;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
}
.title-separator-1{
  border-right:solid 1px #555;
}
.title-separator-2{
  border-right:solid 1.5px #555;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul><li class="title-separator-1">Home</li>
  <li class="title-separator-2">About</li>
  <li class="title-separator-2">
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li class="bottom-separator">Web Design</li>
      <li class="bottom-separator">Web Development</li>
      <li class="bottom-separator">Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="title-separator-1">Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @kailas what about the main title? eg: home,about,portfolion,blog,contact ... i wish to make it like home | about | portfolion | blog | contact

Comment: did you mean right border? I've added that can you please check and let me know if that's what you wanted? or use of Pipes? '|' character?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some separator, you can place a border to the left or right and eliminate the last/first one respectively using the `first-child` or `last-child` pseudo selector.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #2A0851;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white, grey);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, grey);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(white, grey);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.bottom-separator {
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>
      Portfolio
      <ul>
        <li class="bottom-separator">Web Design</li>
        <li class="bottom-separator">Web Development</li>
        <li class="bottom-separator">Illustrations</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add follow css in your style

```
div > ul > li:nth-child(even){
    background: black;
    width: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 3;
 }

div > ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Then update your html:

```
<div>
 <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li></li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li></li>
     <li>Portfolio</li>
     <li></li>
     <ul>
      <li class="bottom-separator">Web Design</li>
      <li class="bottom-separator">Web Development</li>
      <li class="bottom-separator">Illustrations</li>
     </ul>
     <li></li>
     <li>Blog</li>
     <li></li>
     <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```